# All of a sudden vs So suddenly

Tags: word-usage

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> Sentence A : Why are you shouting ***so suddenly*** like that ?
>
> Sentence B : Why are you shouting ***all of a sudden*** like that ?

Which one is correct? If both are correct, which one is more idiomatic?

Comment: ***This*** native speaker would probably say something more like "Why are you **suddenly shouting** like that?", but there's something odd about *like that* in conjunction with present continuous *shouting*. In most contexts it would seem more natural to use either "Why **did** you suddenly shout like that?" or "Why are you suddenly shouting?" (where in principle the second could be extended with *"like **this**"*, but I wouldn't be likely to do so).

Comment: This non-native speaker imagines that the most likely utterance a native speaker would yell out when his or her friend is shouting would be something as simple as "Why are you shouting!" or even "Shut up!" :)

Comment: I think "so suddenly" and "all of a sudden" are both used; neither sounds particularly out-of-place. Although I would agree with @FumbleFingers in that I'd also ask "Why are you suddenly shouting?" there are times when the two phrases you ask about are used. If your real question is, are both "so suddenly" and "all of a sudden" in use, then the answer is [yes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=so+suddenly%2Call+of+a+sudden&year_start=1905&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=6).

Comment: @J.R.: I don't think *all of a sudden* is particularly common in current *spoken* English. To me, it has overtones of outdated children's story books, on a par with *once upon a time* and *lived happily ever after*. But on the whole I tend to agree with Damkerng that there usually wouldn't be much reason to mention the "suddenness" at all. You're more likely to just ask why someone is ***shouting***...

Comment: ...having said that, the counts from Google Books are [change your mind all of a sudden](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22change+your+mind+all+of+a+sudden%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):159, and [suddenly change your mind](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suddenly+change+your+mind%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):2990. So I can't say *all of a sudden* doesn't exist, obviously. But it's not the norm.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've really never heard *all of the sudden* in contexts other than children's stories? In my region of the US, it's quite common. *All of the sudden, she was struck by lightning.* *All of the sudden, out of nowhere, she started shouting at me.*

Comment: @Fumble - I don't think that Google book count is a fair comparison, because it doesn't account for variants like "all of a sudden, you change your mind". Here's [yet another interesting Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happened+all+of+a+sudden%2Chappened+suddenly%2Csuddenly+happened%2Cof+a+sudden+it+happened&year_start=1905&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=6). I think _all of a sudden_ is used enough that I wouldn't call it "outside the norm."

Comment: Moreover, [most of these don't look like children's books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20a%20sudden%20it%20happened%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1991,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en).

Comment: @J.R.: I think we must agree to differ. It may be more common, but I class it in the general category of quirky dialectalisms like [all of a flutter](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/all-of-a-flutter), [all of a doodah](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/all-of-a-doodah), and [all of a dither](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+a+dither)

Comment: @Fumble - If it really sounds that unusual to you, I must wonder if there might not be some BrE/AmE issues here. The phrase doesn't sound the least bit quirky to my American ear. Moreover, I realize we must look at Ngrams with caution, but, in this case, the Ngram [isn't even close](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+of+a+sudden%2Call+of+a+doodah%2Call+of+a+flutter%2Call+of+a+dither&year_start=1905&year_end=2005&corpus=18&smoothing=6).

Comment: @J.R.: I've never suggested the word is particularly "unusual" to me. Simply that *relative to the standard form* it's not very common. And as you so helpfully point out, variants on this non-standard grammar are even *less* common, so it's not particularly useful for learners. And to  back up my point that it's ***relatively*** uncommon, consider these written instance counts...

Comment: ...[all of a sudden stopped](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22all+of+a+sudden+stopped%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):6K, [stopped all of a sudden](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stopped+all+of+a+sudden%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):40K, [suddenly stopped](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suddenly+stopped%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):409K, [stopped suddenly](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stopped+suddenly%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):347K. On any given occasion, a native speaker is over 15 times more likely to use *suddenly* rather than *all of a sudden*.

Comment: I am a native speaker, and I'd say that that still does not make *all of the/a sudden* incorrect. Perhaps it's less common in your region? Ngrams obviously aren't representative of speech, and I'd also question their ability to distinguish between a point as fine as the choice between definite and an indefinite article. Google itself doesn't even use a/an/the in search terms, so I'm not sure they're helpful in this (or most) case(s). I will concede that when I read it **without** *like that*, *so suddenly* does work; but that's not to say that either one is incorrect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I apologize, it appears I'm not as correct as I'd initially [thought](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sudden), and I should have been as firm about this. To me, it's *all of the sudden*, because in the Mid-Atlantic US, it's most commonly uttered as *all the sudden*, which I've heretofore assumed to be a reduction of *all of the sudden*. The most grammatically correct choice is the most commonly said in your region. I'll also further concede that *all of-* or *all the sudden* is informal either way. I'm sorry; in my defense, Ngrams does reflect the shift

Comment: @Fumble - Those numbers say a native _writer_ is more likely to use "suddenly." Everyday speech doesn't always follow the book corpora. Note that I am not arguing that _suddenly_ isn't more common. I'm simply asserting that _all of a sudden_ is common enough that it doesn't sound awkward, unusual, dated, or overly quaint.

Comment: @John Q: I don't know the exact history of how this expression came to survive in modern English. My guess is it's dialectal and/or an affectation (as with *flutter, doodah, dither* 7 comments above this). But none of the variants (*all* omitted, *on* replacing *of*, *the* replacing *a*, etc.) are "grammatical" by current standards. So I don't say your version is any more "wrong" than the others - it's just that (today, at least) ***all of a** sudden* is the most tenacious "survivor". For all that, and J.R.'s position notwithstanding, I'd advise learners not to bother with it at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps you're right regarding this not being appropriate for learners. It is, at best, informal. Initially, *so suddenly* struck me as incorrect as it was written (I would have struck *so* from that sentence and revised it as: *Why are you suddenly shouting?*). The combination of both the prepositional phrases sounded ungrammatical to my ear. You're also right that it's **not standard**; it's dialectal though. I answered in terms of my own dialect, which was a mistake. But I vehemently maintain that dialectal **is not** incorrect in informal speech/writing.

Comment: I should also add that while I'd speak *Why are you suddenly shouting?* formally, I'd almost never phrase it that way amongst friends, which was the other reason I answered as I did; but again, that is anecdotal/dialectal. This may be an *Americanism*, which would explain a lot.

Comment: @John Q: Your link on the 7th comment under your own Q is interesting, because the sudden resurgence of ***the*** is much more pronounced in the US than UK. Curiously, that version was [much more common in BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+of+the+sudden&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20of%20the%20sudden%3B%2Cc0) than [in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+of+the+sudden&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20of%20the%20sudden%3B%2Cc0) 100-200 years ago...

Comment: ...personally, I put it down to the fact that AmE has more "not-quite-native" speakers. Since there's no useful grammatical principle of "correctness" involved here, there's no reason why people shouldn't use ***the*** instead of ***a***. You personally may have learnt the form at your mother's knee, but I doubt that would be the general case. I suspect that often it just *seems* more logical/easy to remember for people who're trying to repeat a "frozen" idiomatic form. But I stand by my assertion that none of the variants embody any useful principles for non-native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm ordinarily sensitive about AmE (because I love my native language), but in this case, what you've said regarding *not-quite-native* speakers is in fact quite correct; I'm only the 3rd generation (2nd native) in my family. I probably wouldn't have pushed so hard had I realized you were British.  I just couldn't fathom you having not heard it before. Additionally, AmE does preserve some English grammar from the Early-Modern period (gotten being most the infamous example) that has long since disappeared in Britain.

Comment: Prior to giving this expression more thought than I'd ever thought possible, I now understand how the two could be misheard. There isn't much difference between /ov-ə/ and /ov-thə/. I would never hear the difference in natural speech were I not looking for it. And I concur regarding the usefulness to non-native speakers in all but one aspect: the most obvious marker of a non-native speaker is that the grammar is a bit too perfect, and the words a bit *too big*. I wanted to replicate natural speech, but perhaps failed.

Comment: Here's one thing we've all missed in the OP: *Which one is correct? If both are correct, **which one is more idiomatic?***, That actually makes the answer **(B)**.

Comment: @John Q: I don't recall saying I've *never* heard your version - just that it's far less common than the "standard" one (even in AmE, but obviously there can be "dialectal pockets" where other variants predominate). My main point is that "correct" is an almost meaningless concept in respect of frozen idiomatic forms that don't reflect current grammar. Personally, I think *none* of the variants were ever really "grammatical" according to "standard" usage at any time in the past, but in certain times and places some or all were perhaps "less ungrammatical" than they are today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've re-read the MW definition that I linked above, and they've marked *all of a sudden* as obsolete. So yes, you're correct that it's non-standard, even in AmE. Let me put it this way: It's archaic, it's retained in some pockets colloquially, and it's definitely idiomatic. If you ever find yourself in New York or Philadelphia, no one would bat an eyelash should you use phrase in conversation. Since I grew up between those cities, I yielded your AmE point. And while I agree your points, I think my point was that we allow/expect things in speech that we'd never accept in writing.

Comment: @John Q: We've probably done this one to death by now, but I must just say I think you/M-W are putting it a bit strong to say the usage is "obsolete/archaic". It's just not exactly "standard/mainstream" these days, so I'd advise users not to spend time either committing the the expression to memory, or trying to understand how the "grammar" works. The current adjectival usage *(rapid, unexpected)* fits current grammar, but OED lists a dozen or more *obsolete* usages that don't. And they certainly don't label ***all of a sudden*** as obsolete - I think it's just a "frozen form".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I meant to ask for the OED version, but I didn't want to add to the length of the discussion. I don't personally feel that it's obsolete, but if I'm advising someone on AmE, I go with what MW says.

Comment: @John Q: Well, it's not entirely clear from their entry, but I think M-W are saying the *general* use of *(noun) sudden = an unexpected occurrence* is obsolete. That doesn't mean the specific fixed phrase we're looking at is obsolete, any more than [*wrought iron*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrought_iron) is obsolete just because we no longer use *wrought* as a past participle of the verb ***to work***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand what you're saying now. They mean that that the usage as a noun is obsolete, and that it only lingers in one remaining idiom. In other words, don't use it any other way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can see that you've discussed this at length, but I wanted to add another thought to this. You're of course right that *all of a/the sudden* is less common than *suddenly*. I think part of this can be attributed to *when* it seems appropriate to use each (at least to my AmE ear!). *Suddenly* is of course used when events are sudden; *Suddenly the door flew open!* In my experience, *all of the sudden* is more often used to express *disbelief*, not just suddenness. *What, and he's decided he's liberal all of the sudden?* Worth noting, at least!

Comment: (My point being that *suddenly* would be acceptable in either instance, but that *all of the sudden* is significantly more common (in my experience) in the latter.)

Comment: It's a long list of comments, I have no time to read at this time or any time soon. However, a comment made by @FumbleFingers I strongly disagree with her as a ELL is this: "so it's not particularly useful for learners." IF it means censoring less formal English to ELL. You could inform the learners but not censor what could be useful for them. Let them decide.

Comment: @learner: Your comment seems somewhat self-defeating. If you don't have the time (or, apparently, the inclination) to read a lengthy discussion on these fine points, how are you to know what if any difference there is between *suddenly* and *all of/on a/the sudden*? And as per the points raised between myself and John Q Public, even native speakers may not realise how significantly "regional" their idiomatic usage is. If you came out with *all **on the** sudden* in the UK because you'd found it here as "informal", you'd sound ignorant, not well-versed and natural.

Comment: My comment is not about the details of differences of suddenly or all of a sudden? It is about deciding what English learners should know and should not know. This reminds me of what prescriptivists' approach to Grammar. The right way to me as an English learner is to inform the learner about the point and advise them but not just decide for them. The idea is to make them "aware". I made this comment because I came across a comment like yours and it might be made by you but it's not important by who. What's important is ... follows below

Comment: so what's important is how English learners should be answered. This is my opinion and I strongly believe in it. Depending on the level of the learner, they would take in as much as their level let them do. What doesn't make sense to them, makes more sense to others.

Answer (score 4):

The comments on the question have been quite enlightening. I would've thought this a simpler question, so I'll risk posting the simple answer, but I owe credit to the commentators, so I'll make this a community wiki and encourage them to edit if they disagree with this answer as a summary.

**Simple answer:** Both are correct; Sentence B is more idiomatic.

*Complex answer*: see comments!

Comment: At the risk of despoiling this perfectly reasonable answer with a comment, I would just say that I would *usually* understand that "short answer" as implying native speakers *usually* use B. In reality *neither* of these exact utterances are particularly common for the context, but regarding the specific difference *A:suddenly, B:all of a/the sudden*, A is about 15 times more common than B.

Answer (score -2):

There is something worth remarking about here first which is tangential, and that is this: we have a progressive action ("to be shouting") which is being combined with "suddenly".

Now, you cannot suddenly do something which is ongoing, or habitual.

> Why are you shouting suddenly like that?

means that "You are showing a new behavior of shouting that may be ongoing or habitual from now on for some time. Why did you suddenly switch to this behavior?"

It is different from:

> Why did you shout suddenly like that?

which only asks about the one time that the other person shouted, without assuming that shouting is going to be a persistent behavior.

An important point here is that the first sentence only makes sense if the speaker has a reason to believe that the shouting is a new mode of behavior that shows signs of continuing. The second sentence can be used even if an indefinite amount of time has passed since the other person last shouted.

Anyway, on to the topic:

"all of a sudden" and "suddenly" are not quite interchangeable. "suddenly" can replace "all of a sudden", but "all of a sudden" can only replace "suddenly" when "suddenly" is used as a word which introduces an entire clause. When suddenly is close to the verb, functioning as an adjective, then "all of a sudden" can be awkward. It depends on how it is positioned. If it can be introduced as a kind of parenthetical comment, then it works.

> Why did you shout {suddenly | all of a sudden?} like that?
>
> Why did you suddenly shout like that?
>
> Why did you, all of a sudden, shout like that?

The second example is fine because "all of a sudden" isn't being forced to function as an adverb. It's a kind of comment, and in that area of language there is a lot of flexibility.

In the 1978 comedy movie *High Anxiety* there is a lovable character named Dr. Vicktor Lillolman (the name Lillolman being a word play on "little old man"). The elderly psychiatrist is obviously a non-native speaker of English, speaking with a German-like accent. One of the cute mistakes that he makes is to misuse "all of a sudden", when he speaks the following line in response to Dr. Thorndike:

> Thorndike: Your predecessor, Dr. Ashley, hired me.
>
> Lillolman: It's a shame he died so ... all of a sudden.

Lillolman pauses briefly trying to think of the right English word, and the obvious joke is that he is able to think of the awkwardly-fitting "all of sudden", yet it does not occur to him to use the obvious and correct adverb "suddenly" which is closely related to "all of a sudden".

Comment: You're slightly misunderstanding the progressive tenses. When you say, *Why are you suddenly shouting [like that]?* you're just asking why **they've just begun** shouting. That does not mean their shouting has ceased. They may or may not have heard you ask the question (i.e. they may or may not be shouting *while you're talking*). If you're conversing with someone, as we're doing here and now, are we **both** continuously talking? But we are/were talking, no? When you've got both American and  British native speakers in agreement, that should tell you it's ***standard English***.